# Swipe delete row issue for UITableview

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios-simulator

This is gonna drive me crazy! Lots of similar questions, but I still cant seem to figure out why this swipe-to-delete code of mine doesn't work! The 'Delete' button just doesn't appear. Is there some special way of swiping in the UITableview cell, in the simulator, compared to the device?
This is the code,

`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
{

return YES;
}


-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}



-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}




// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
    [attachmentsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [tableView reloadData];
}   

}
```

update - placed break points at `canEditRowAtIndexPath,editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath, commitEditingStyle` but the control never goes to commitEditingStyle. It just keeps looping between the first two.

Comment: issue resolved! :) the width of the table view was larger than the view, that is why I could never see the delete button. Side note: If a class has been subclassed from table view, then no need implement the first three methods, just commitEditingStyle method would do.